# Cannot connect to Atlas MongoDB from Azure Functions

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-functions, database-connection

I just created an Azure Function that should connect to my instance of MongoDB on Atlas, basically following this tutorial:

https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/how-to-integrate-azure-functions-with-mongodb

From my local development with Visual Studio, everything works fine and I can connect to the Atlas environment, but when I deploy the code on Azure, the following exception raises:

> A timeout occurred after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 }, OperationsCountServerSelector }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", ConnectionMode : "ReplicaSet", Type : "ReplicaSet", State : "Disconnected", Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/ltdevcluster-shard-00-00.qkeby.mongodb.net:27017" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/ltdevcluster-shard-00-00.qkeby.mongodb.net:27017", ReasonChanged: "Heartbeat", State: "Disconnected", ServerVersion: , TopologyVersion: , Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server.
> ---> MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while receiving a message from the server.
> ---> System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Attempted to read past the end of the stream.

If I instead set the Network Access to "everywhere", again everything works fine.

Now, in the Network Access panel of Atlas, I added the IPs retrieved from the Azure Portal under my function app => Networking => Inbound traffic and Outbound traffic (a total of 1 IP for inbound and 3 IPs for outbound).

But adding those 4 IPs has not solved the issue.

What else should I do?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using static IP, for a workaround, you can check this: [How do I set a static IP in Functions?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-networking-faq#how-do-i-set-a-static-ip-in-functions)

You can also [set up a Private Endpoint](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-private-endpoint/) and for the security of the database credentials check [secrets engine integration using vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/secrets/mongodbatlas).

You can refer to [How to connect Azure Function with MongoDB Atlas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/343624/how-to-connect-azure-function-with-mongodb-atlas.html)  ,[Azure functions unable to connect with Mongo Db Atlas M10](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/azure-functions-unable-to-connect-with-mongo-db-atlas-m10/99057) and [How to connect Azure Function with MongoDB Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/how-to-connect-azure-function-with-mongodb-atlas/101565)

Comment: Hi @DeepDave-MT, if I understood correctly, these options are available for the premium plans. Is there a way to do that with the Free tier? i.e. Atlas M0 Sandbox?

Comment: Yes, you can do it with a free tier with some limitations. You can refer to [MongoDB Atlas free on Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/es-es/blog/microsoft-azure-tutorial-how-to-integrate-azure-functions-with-mongodb/) and [Atlas M0 (Free Cluster) Limitations](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/free-shared-limitations/)

Comment: So the answer to my question is basically "No, you cannot do this connection using the M0 free tier"?

Comment: Yes, only possible with some [Configuration Limitations](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/free-shared-limitations/)